# How to access list items inner html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript snippet which accepts a text input, traverses through ul > li, and filters the items based on their inner html.

```
 var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById('inputSerachBox');
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("ulWithItems");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

        // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

Now I am trying to convert this snippet to jQUery and doing this but getting an error `html is not a function`:

```
$('#inputSerachBox').on('keyup', function (e) {
            var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
            input = $('#inputSerachBox');
            filter = input.val().toUpperCase();
            li = $('#ulWithItems li');
            li.each(function (e) {               
                a = $('a', e)[0];
                if (a.html().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    console.log(a.html())
                    e.style.display = "";
                } else {
                    e.style.display = "none";
                }
            })

        })
```

Are my selectors wrong?

Comment: Try `a = $('a', e).eq(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you need the first element so you cannot use `[0]` as it does not gives you a JQuery object. Instead, it gives you a `HTML` element in which you cannot use `html()` function.

What you need is to use either `eq()` or `get()` method as,

```
 li.each(function (e) {               
    a = $('a', e).eq(0);
     if (a.html().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        console.log(a.html())
        e.style.display = "";
     } else {
        e.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

**OR**

```
 li.each(function (e) {               
    a = $('a', e).first();
     if (a.html().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        console.log(a.html())
        e.style.display = "";
     } else {
        e.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `$('a', e)[0]` yields a native DOM object, not a jQuery object, so that's why it doesn't have an `html()` function. Try `$('a', e).first()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('a', e)[0];` does  not return a JQuery element. Change `a = $('a', e)[0];` to `a = $($('a', e)[0]);`